# Magento 2 Product page title different from meta title

Tags: magento2.3.0, meta-tags

I don't know if I'm being daft here or what but my product page is showing product name as the title in browser tab and it is ignoring the meta title set in the Search Engine Optimization Meta Title field. If I look through the source code it is pulling it through correctly.

So my source code is as below:

```
<meta name="title" content="Blank White 480-Micron Self-Adhesive Plastic Cards | Low Prices 24/7"/>
<title>Blank White Self-Adhesive 480-Micron Plastic Cards (100 Pack)</title>
```

It works perfectly on category page though so both page title and meta title are the same.

I'm on Magento 2.3.0.

Comment: You got any solution for this?

Comment: @devtype did you got solutions ?

Comment: @Piyush did you get solutions?